# React Navigation routes disappear from history on navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen in my app (CameraScreen) that is both in my Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator shown below (there are some more Tab Screens and Stack Screens that I removed for simplicity):

```
const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Camera"
        component={CameraScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={Theme}>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Camera" component={TabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={ProductScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="CameraStack" component={CameraScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Now if I navigate to ProductScreen, then navigate to CameraStack from there and check the navigation state I notice that ProductScreen is nowhere to be found in the routes which I checked using `navigation.getState().routes`. Thus if I try and use `navigation.goBack()` it does not go back to the ProductScreen (which would be the expected behaviour).

When I check the routes in ProductScreen, ProductScreen shows up as the last route, however this disappears when I navigate to CameraStack.

I have a hunch that this has to do with the fact that CameraScreen is in both the Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator so for some reason the `navigation` prop passed to Camera is the Tab Navigator.

For reference my CameraScreen (simplified):

```
const CameraScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  // this doesn't include ProductScreen even if I navigate to CameraStack from the ProductScreen
  console.log(navigation.getState().routes);
  return (
    <View></View>
  );
};
```

and ProductScreen (simplified):

```
const ProductScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CameraStack")}
        >
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

One idea I can think of to resolve this issue is to manually pass a navigation parameter from ProductScreen but I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I realized this had nothing to do with the fact that I had this screen in both the Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator but was occurring because I was navigating to the same screen using `navigation.navigate` instead of `navigation.push`.

The former navigates to the previous location in your stack if you navigate to a screen you've already visited before, but the latter pushes a new route to the navigation state even if it's a screen you've already visited.

Answer (score 1):

Handle   `backBehavior`   prop in your Navigator

```
<Tab.Navigator backBehavior='history'>
    <Screen ... />
    <Screen ... />
<Tab.Navigator/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#backbehavior